# Post JSON reqeust to URL using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, curl, post, servicenow

I need to post json request to url with powershell.
The curl body looks like that:

```
{
"records":
[ {
     \"source\" : \"Pinger\",
    \"node\" : \"nameofnode\",
    \"type\" : \"ICMP\",
    \"resource\" : \"C:\",
    \"severity\" : \”0\",
    \"description\" : \"No ping to host\",
   
  }
```

]
}

I am trying with this :

```
$jsonreqUP=@{ 
    records= @(
    @{
         source="Pinger"
         node= $i
         type="ICMP"
         resource="switch"
         severity=0  
        description="No ping to host $i"
       
      }
   )
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://justasite.com/jsonv2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" } -Credential $creds -Method POST -Body $jsonreqUP -ContentType "application/json"
```

I am getting error : Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
$i hold a hostname variable.

What is wrong with my transformation?

Many thnaks in advance!

Comment: Your resource argument is different.

Comment: Severity is a string in your original sample, and a number in your second.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I cleared out both things, but the error remains. Will have to check further.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading found that the I am missing| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 after the last closng } :)